# Gaps and Island

Tags: sql-server, date, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with StartDate and EndDate. I wanted to get the missing Date and The script I have does it. But for instance

### LocationID StartDate EndDate

1 2020-01-01 2020-01-03

1 2020-01-04 2020-01-05

1 2020-01-10 2020-01-15

```
DECLARE @t table(PlaceID int, StartDate date, EndDate date);

INSERT @t(PlaceID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES
(1,'20200101','20200103'),(1,'20200104','20200105'),(1,'20200110','20200115'),
--(2,'20200103','20200106'),(2,'20200107','20200110'),(2,'20200120','20200123');


-- input parameters 
DECLARE @PlaceIDofInterest   int  = 1,
        @StartDateOfInterest date = '20200101', 
        @EndDateOfInterest   date = '20200131';
    
;WITH date_range(d) AS -- the entire range of days we care about
(
  SELECT @StartDateOfInterest UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, d) FROM date_range
         WHERE d < @EndDateOfInterest
),
islands AS -- grouped sets of days _not_ covered
(
  SELECT r.d, island = DATEADD(DAY, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY r.d) * -1, r.d) 
    FROM date_range AS r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @t AS t
      ON  r.d >= t.StartDate 
      AND r.d <= t.EndDate
      AND t.PlaceID = @PlaceIDofInterest
    WHERE t.PlaceID IS NULL
)
SELECT  MIN(d) as STARTDATE , MAX(d) as ENDDATE-- for each island, grab the start and end
  FROM islands 
 
  GROUP BY island 
  ORDER BY MIN(d);
```

The output I get is,

### STARTDATE ENDDATE

2020-01-06 2020-01-09

2020-01-16 2020-01-31

But I wanted the output as,

### STARTDATE ENDDATE

2020-01-03 2020-01-04

2020-01-05 2020-01-10

2020-01-15 2020-01-31

What changes can i make ?

A location can be booked from night to morning. So StartDate Night to EndDate Morning. SO the Location will be free on EndDate night, unless it is booked. Also the Location will be free on Startdate Morning.

1st of Jan to 3rd of Jan is booked - that means from 1st night to 3rd morning. next booking is only on 4th night. So the location is free from 3rd night to 4th morning too. So i would need the result to have 3rd an as start date and 4thJan as enddate in one row. Hope this is clear.

Thanks

Comment: [duplicate on dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/278192/gaps-and-islands).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't lie, I have probably overly complicated this a bit, but this is the direction I had gone, so I saw it through to the end. I do, however, replace your rCTE with a Tally, which for much larger sets should be (significantly) more performant. You likely, as well, need to add `PARTITION BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses on `PlaceID`, but as the samples were based on 1 place, I have not implemented this.

```sql
DECLARE @t table(PlaceID int, StartDate date, EndDate date);

INSERT @t(PlaceID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES
(1,'20200101','20200103'),(1,'20200104','20200105'),(1,'20200110','20200115');
--(2,'20200103','20200106'),(2,'20200107','20200110'),(2,'20200120','20200123');


-- input parameters 
DECLARE @PlaceIDofInterest   int  = 1,
        @StartDateOfInterest date = '20200101', 
        @EndDateOfInterest   date = '20200131';
    
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDateOfInterest,@EndDateOfInterest)+1)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --1000 days
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, I, @StartDateOfInterest) AS [Date]
    FROM Tally),
Gaps AS(
    SELECT D.[Date],
           CASE LAG(DATEADD(DAY,1,D.[Date]),1,D.[Date]) OVER (ORDER BY D.[Date]) WHEN D.Date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Check]
    FROM Dates D
         LEFT JOIN @t t ON D.[Date] >= t.StartDate
                       AND D.[Date] < t.EndDate
    WHERE t.PlaceID IS NULL),
Grps AS(
    SELECT [Date],
           COUNT(CASE [Check] WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
    FROM Gaps)
SELECT MIN([Date]) AS StartDate,
       MAX(CASE [Date] WHEN @EndDateOfInterest THEN [Date] ELSE DATEADD(DAY,1,[Date]) END) AS EndDate
FROM Grps
GROUP BY Grp;
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I exceed the days to more than 1000 days please ?

Comment: Just add more cross joins to `N`, @Jeni . Though 1,000 days is almost 3 years, so I assumed that would be enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot. much appreciated @Larnu

Comment: You#re welcome, @Jeni . If this does answer the question, please do mark it as the solution so that future readers know it was helpful. Thanks.